# Oracle Max Timetamp- subtract 45 minutes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to build a query, which returns all records 45 Minutes before the max timestamp.

For example the record with the latest timestamp is:

```
01.09.2013 11:00:00
```

Now I would like to have all records from

```
01.09.2013 10:15:00 to 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with cte as
  (select max(the_timestamp_field) the_timestamp_field
     from test)    
select
    *
from
    test,cte
where
    test.the_timestamp_field between cte.the_timestamp_field - (1/24*.75)
                                 and  cte.the_timestamp_field
```

will do it.

Comment: +1 This should perform better on large datasets than the analytic solution if there is an index on `the_timestamp_field`.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by using `Max` aggregate/analytic function and `interval` statement:
Here is an example:

```
   select col  
    from ( select col
                , max(col) over() as max_time
            from t1) t
   where t.col between t.max_time - interval '45' minute 
                   and t.max_time
```

Result:

```
Col 
--------------------
01.09.13 11:00:00 AM 
01.09.13 10:45:00 AM 
01.09.13 10:30:00 AM 
01.09.13 10:15:00 AM
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00f24/2)

Answer (score 0):

It can be simple and a little complicated, depending on how do you want to determine the creation time of the record. If there is a date column in your table which indicates the creation time it's simple:

```
SELECT columns
FROM table
WHERE date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01.09.2013 10:15', 'MM.DD.YYYY HH24:MI') AND
TO_DATE('01.09.2013 11:00', 'MM.DD.YYYY HH24:MI')
```

If there is no date column you can use `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP`(`ORA_ROWSCN`) pseudo column to determine the creation time, but please note that this feture requires `10g` or greater version.

Comment: Indeed, there is a column which indicates the date & time.
Your select statement works correctly for a fixed time. But I would like to achieve that a bit more dynamically. I don't really know what the maximum timestamp value might be :).